# Is there a way to define a custom skills values each time the skill gets invoked?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am attempting to make a skill which can select files, Unfortunately the AMAZON.LITERAL type is being deprecated and I need to update my skill to a custom skill type. I already have code that generates keywords for selectable files, is there a way to overwrite or append the custom skill keywords automatically with each invocation? Or at least a way to trick Alexa into collecting semi free form speech?

Comment: you can try in a different way maybe.. Alexa can read the file list like "Here is your files say 1 for fileexample1 say 2 for file example, 3 fileexample4.. say go next to continue reading the list".. I know it's not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a way to update the custom skill keywords (the custom slot value item list) with each invocation?*

No.  For each custom slot you must specify a static list when you define your skill.  ([Here's a](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/content/idea/45116/dynamic-or-per-user-value-list-for-custom-slots.html) feature request to make the list dynamic.

*Or at least a way to trick Alexa into collecting semi free form speech?*

Sort of.  In response to developer's dissapointment about the loss of the literal type Amazon has recently been emphasizing that the list of items you supply for the custom slot is just a guide, and that the custom slot can still act a fair bit like the literal slot.  See this blog post for details...

[Why a Custom Slot is the Literal Solution](https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/Why-a-Custom-Slot-is-the-Literal-Solution)

Comment: Yeah, That's what I thought was the answer. Thanks for posting those links though. They are extremely helpful.